# How to workaround a Layout Animation pre Honeycomp

Tags: android, animation, layout

I read a lot about Animation pre Honeycomp, and that changes only take account inside drawing. I have to support versions down to 2.1, so `Animator` isn't an Option, too.

I have a LinearLayout, containing two Buttons laying on the right side of the screen. On some Events I Animate the right Button out of the View. Unfortunately the Click-ecents are registered on their original positions. As a workaround, I added an `AnimationListener`, and set the Buttons visibility to `View.GONE` on AnimationEnd, and bring it back with `View.VISIBLE` if the Button is animated In again. This leads to an ugly flash of the Layout which is animated if I apply the Visibility.

Is there another way to keep track of the Views after the Animation? Can I remove a View, without resulting in a flash inside the containing Layout (maybe some sort of doubleBuffering)?

**EDIT:**
the term `Flash` means that the view dissaperas on its Position for a very short period and appears after it again on the same Position. It happens exactly if `onAnimation[Start|End]` changes something inside that Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by "flash" , do you mean that the views jump to their new location? or do you mean that during the transition between the animation end , there is something that looks like a bug that moves the view for a split of a second to its original position?

in any case , here's a sample code that worked for me on a similar scenario . you will of course need to change it. i hope it could help you:

```
final int deltaXToMove=50;
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0,deltaXToMove,0,0);
int animationTime=1000;
translateAnimation.setDuration(animationTime);
translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams par=(LayoutParams)b.getLayoutParams();
    par.leftMargin=deltaXToMove;
    b.setLayoutParams(par);
    }
...
b.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Comment: look at my edit, to see what I mean by `flash`. I also tried your implementation, but it seems that `setFillAfter(false)` has no effect inside `onAnimationEnd`. Also if I leave it and change the values accordingly, the `flash` appears again.

Comment: i don't understand . does the flash bug occur on my implementation (without any changes to it) ?

Comment: I only changed deltaX, and I have a RelativeLayout

Comment: please try to use it on a frameLayout and tell me if it works for you, as i haven't tested it on other layouts. they are probably the same , but i want to be sure.